# how to write the sql query for this condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| id  | grade_id | student_id | subject_id |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
| 249 |        1 |         27 |          1 |
| 250 |        1 |         27 |          2 |
| 251 |        1 |         27 |          4 |
| 252 |        1 |         28 |          1 |
| 253 |        1 |         28 |          2 |
| 254 |        1 |         28 |          4 |
| 255 |        1 |         29 |          1 |
| 256 |        2 |         29 |          2 |
| 257 |        3 |         29 |          4 |
+-----+----------+------------+------------+
```

I am a beginner in sql queries. I need the student_id's from the above table having for each subject_id the grade_id should be 1.And Also i need the count of students having grade_id = 1 for all subject_id.

Comment: What would the desired result set look like? And what have you tried?

Comment: i need to get the result as student_id 27 and 28.Because student_id 27 and 28 having grade_id = 1 for all subject_id s.

Comment: Please have a try first before asking for help. This is a site where we help people, not a site where we do jobs of others for free.

Comment: sorry sir, i dont know how to express my doubt, and the solution for this one.

Comment: @nidhin what fancy means and also strawberry is: Did you try a sql statement already? If so which one. As this site is here so that people can help with problems. What this site is not about is doing the work for someone just because. Thus if you have a problem for example you have tried a specific sql command but are not sure why it does not give the appropriate result then this is perfect for this site (if google does not reveal something in the first try) but if you just say "I have this and this situation now do something" this is the wrong site then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want those students with `1`for all subjects:

```
SELECT student_id 
FROM Table
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING MAX(grade_id) = MIN(grade_id) -- only one grade
   AND MIN(grade_id) = 1
```

If your grades are `>= 1` only

```
SELECT student_id 
FROM Table
GROUP BY student_id
HAVING MAX(grade_id) = 1   -- no grade greater than 1
```

And for counting you simply nest this query in a Derived Table:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
 (
   SELECT student_id 
   FROM Table
   GROUP BY student_id
   HAVING MAX(grade_id) = MIN(grade_id) -- only one grade
      AND MIN(grade_id) = 1
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: Yeah, good job. I was about to write a "teach a man to fish" answer. Thanks to you questions like this are more and more flooding this site. Can't you see where this is going? Lower and lower quality. Think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return students which have no other grade_id than 1:

```
 select distinct student_id
 from tablename t1
 where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                   where t2.student_id = t1.student_id
                     and t2.grade_id <> 1)
```

(`SELECT DISTINCT` to return each student only once.)

To count these students, use a derived table:

```
select count(*)
from
(
 select distinct student_id
 from tablename t1
 where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                   where t2.student_id = t1.student_id
                     and t2.grade_id <> 1)
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Your 1st query requirements isn't very clear, please elaborate.

For the 2nd one (if I understand correctly):

```
SELECT subject_id, COUNT(student_id) 
FROM Table WHERE grade_id = 1 
GROUP BY subject_id
```

Comment: i need the students who having grade_id 1 for all subjects listed in table.Please understand me and help me.